# Change LogOn properties of a SQL server instance

Tags: sql-server, wmi

I want to change the logon properties of a sql server 2008 r2 instance by using code.
Manually i can do it in SQL server configuration manager by right clicking on instance name->Log On. Under Built-in account change Network service to Local service. Then click on apply. SQL instance will be restarted to effect the changes.

Now hoe can i do the same(Network service to Local service) using  code .I think it can be done using WMI. So please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing logon properties from Network service to localSystem can be done by using WMI.

Use [Change method of the Win32_Service class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In change method specify first 6 parameters blank and then specify StartName as LocalSystem(You can also specify other parameters such as login names if required) and StartPassword as a blank password(Blank password in case of localsystem).

Below is a vbscript to do it.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Service where Name = 'MSSQL$Instancename'")
For Each objService in colServices
    errReturn = objService.Change( , , , , , , "LocalSystem","")     
Next
```

Also see [this link](http://include.wutils.com/wmi/ROOT/cimv2/CIM_ManagedSystemElement/CIM_LogicalElement/CIM_Service/Win32_BaseService.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use PowerShell.  [This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a6b2cba0-2d00-442a-a045-279baa8e92c3/smo-and-wmi-to-change-sql-service-account-credentials) post has code that worked for me in the past.  As stated in the article you have to run PowerShell as an admin or you will get errors.  Going to copy the relevant part in case the link goes offline at some point...

```
#Load the assembly containing the objects used in this example
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")

#Declare Variables
$SQLServiceAccount = 'DOMAIN\username'
$SQLServiceAccountPassword = 'XXXXXXX'

#Get a managed computer instance
$mc = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer

#List out all sql server instnces running on this mc
foreach ($Item in $mc.Services){$Item.Name}

#Get the default sql server datbase engine service
$svc = $mc.Services["MSSQLSERVER"]

# for stopping and starting services PowerShell must run as administrator

#Stop this service
$svc.Stop()
$svc.Refresh()
while ($svc.ServiceState -ne "Stopped")
{
$svc.Refresh()
$svc.ServiceState
}
"Service" + $svc.Name + " is now stopped"

#change service account credentials
$svc.SetServiceAccount($SQLServiceAccount,$SQLServiceAccountPassword)

"Starting " + $svc.Name
$svc.Start()
$svc.Refresh()
while ($svc.ServiceState -ne "Running")
{
$svc.Refresh()
$svc.ServiceState
}
$svc.ServiceState
"Service" + $svc.Name + "is now started"
```

Comment: I find WMI solution using vbscript easy than powershell. Because it is easy to implement.please see my answer for my own question.

Comment: SQLWMI should be used for managing SQL Server service accounts. Using WMI or the services console will not propagate the necessary changes for the service account permissions that SQL Server requires to run the service (e.g. access to database file directories, etc.)